# evernote findNotesMetadata - using offset and maxnotes to loop to retrieve all notes

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

Per Evernote [documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) for findNotesMetadata the maxnotes returned from server in 1 response is 250. I am trying to understand how to make multiple requests to retrieve entire array if more then 250. Below is current code.

```
const Evernote = require('evernote');
const developerToken = "...";
const client = new Evernote.Client({token: developerToken, sandbox: false});
const noteStore = client.getNoteStore();
const spec = {}
  spec.includeTitle = true;
  spec.includeTagGuids = true;
  spec.includeAttributes = true;
  spec.includeNotebookGuid = true;
const filter = new Evernote.NoteStore.NoteFilter({
  words: '*',
});

noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 250, spec)
  .then(noteobj => {  
   ...
  })
  .catch( e => console.error(e));
```

Current code doenst incorporate any loop yet but works up to 250 notes. Due to Evernote SDK and dealing with promises Im not positive even where to start. I have searched online quite a bit to find a solution directly (looking at Evernote examples) and indirectly (looking at other rest API examples). Not having any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `offset` param to `findNotesMetadata` is how you indicate the start index into the actual result set you want. In the case of the code you've shown, you're passing in `0` (it's the second param). That is telling the API that you want your results to begin with item 0 in the actual result set, up to a maximum of 250 results.

If you want to "page" through the result set in windows of 250 results, you can call the method again using 250 as the offset, and ask for the next 250 results. This is a fairly common design pattern for paging through result sets via a remote API or anything that has a resource constraint on retrieving data. You'll want to handle the cases when no more results are available-- either because you get fewer back than the `maxNotes` that you ask for or the corner case where you get exactly the max number but then zero on the following request. That's how you know to break out of your loop.

The Evernote API seems to offer a `findNoteCounts` method, which should give you an idea of how many actual results there would be, but as with all async systems, there's a theoretical race where that number changes between API calls.